# Why does this transaction use the same address for multiple inputs?

Tags: address-reuse

Why does [this transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/61bb6654948b5681f11ad45ec1f9a7ef1bc55826806479058e0f7deab50d7989) include the same address multiple times? Was this done to "hide" the two other addresses where funds originated?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to guess on "intention" of the sender. But let's say I collected many small payments (some Satoshis) in my system. Similiar like many small pennies or cents in a FIAT wallet. Then I have for each payment a UTXO. Now I want to transfer all these little payments (or pennies and cents). The wallet has to collect all UTXOs from that address, and create one output for it. This makes then appear many small amounts from the originating address.

Further detail: I had collected many small amounts at the beginning via  bitcoin faucets, then had many, many small amounts in my wallet, and then transferred it. E.g.: https://blockchain.info/de/tx/c9908124e59a2794f3807b366be7d235ff7654251adcdf396e209236341b3c32

Answer (score -2):

you've got a misunderstanding here because you have no Idea how a transaction actually works in the blockchain, there is no such thing as address balances, all an address has is references to prior addresses that have sent funds to it,hence when an address wants to spend its received funds,it uses the 'inputs' section to refer to their parent transaction outputs,for each one it creates a signature signed by the private key plus the public key.
30440220140048ae789901e73f0644433858de76d762fb37d904e3ad07cfd25bf81255700220545518ea9ed0f866e8088a369d061d068ac5c0644f6782770d6004d8bc39a23b01(signature)
0224e4d74883713b9f6170adf3f8224eabfaacf082b126022827002efdc74aeb02 (public key)